# Como enviar datos y archivos por ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, archivo

Hola tengo un problema al tratar de enviar datos y tambien un archivo de imagen por ajax:

el archivo lo obtengo asi:

```
var form_data = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]); //solo existe 1 input file en ese form
```

ademas tengo datos como:

```
nombre: "Jhon",
datos: array[1,2,3,4]
```

Lo que deseo hacer es enviar por ajax ambos, tanto el archivo como los datos.

Este es el codigo que tengo.

```
 $.ajax({
    //data: form_data //Cuando envio solo el archivo - funciona
   data: {
     nombre:"Jhon",
     datos: array[1,2,3,4],
     imagen: form_data 
    },//Cuando envio de esta manera sale error.
    url: "php/recibo.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {}
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Alguna sugerencia?  Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes es enviar todo el contenido del formulario si es que tus inputs esta dentro de uno, en caso contrario utiliza el método formData.append para agregar información a tu objeto

ejemplo:

```
    var formElement = document.getElementById("#formulario");
    formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append('datos', new Array(1,2,3,4));
    formData.append("nombre","Jhon");// esto si requieres agregar un dato a tu objeto
    $.ajax({
        //data: form_data //Cuando envio solo el archivo - funciona
        data: formData,
        url: "php/recibo.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {}
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, he utilizado esa funcion, pero los arreglos que tengo los convierte en string "1,2,3,4" y llegan al controlador de esa manera. y con la manera normal enviando datos en data funciona pero no he logrado enviar ambos , archivo y datos.

Comment: uliliza formData.append('datos', new Array(1,2,3,4))

Answer (score 0):

Buenas te recomiendo realizar esta tarea utilizando FormData(), que envia el formulario completo, puedes buscar información aquí mismo, o en google, si no sabes como recuperar los datos en el php dímelo en comentario y te ayudo

```
 $("#formulario").on('submit', function(e){
  $.ajax({
    //data: form_data //Cuando envio solo el archivo - funciona
   data: {
     new FormData(this),
    },//Cuando envio de esta manera sale error.
    url: "php/recibo.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {}
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```